# How to write a list of array in a for loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

Hi I neeed to do this one in a loop, but I don't have any idea how to do. I can't do this by just simply incrementing it.

```
CheckBox[] checkboxarray;

checkboxarray = new CheckBox[] { 
    txtChckBx0,  txtChckBx1,  txtChckBx2,  txtChckBx3,  txtChckBx4,  txtChckBx5, 
    txtChckBx6,  txtChckBx7,  txtChckBx8,  txtChckBx9,  txtChckBx10, txtChckBx11, 
    txtChckBx12, txtChckBx13, txtChckBx14, txtChckBx15, txtChckBx16, txtChckBx17, 
    txtChckBx18, txtChckBx19, txtChckBx20, txtChckBx21, txtChckBx22, txtChckBx23, 
    txtChckBx24, txtChckBx25, txtChckBx26, txtChckBx27, txtChckBx28, txtChckBx29, 
    txtChckBx30, txtChckBx31, txtChckBx32, txtChckBx33, txtChckBx34, txtChckBx35, 
    txtChckBx36, txtChckBx37, txtChckBx38, txtChckBx39, txtChckBx40, txtChckBx41, 
    txtChckBx42, txtChckBx43, txtChckBx44, txtChckBx45, txtChckBx46, txtChckBx47, 
    txtChckBx48, txtChckBx49, txtChckBx50, txtChckBx51, txtChckBx52, txtChckBx53,
    txtChckBx54, txtChckBx55, txtChckBx56, txtChckBx57, txtChckBx58, txtChckBx59, 
    txtChckBx60, txtChckBx61, txtChckBx62, txtChckBx63, txtChckBx64, txtChckBx65, 
    txtChckBx66, txtChckBx67, txtChckBx68, txtChckBx69, txtChckBx70, txtChckBx71, 
    txtChckBx72, txtChckBx73, txtChckBx74, txtChckBx75, txtChckBx76, txtChckBx77, 
    txtChckBx78, txtChckBx79, txtChckBx80
};
```

Answer (score 4):

If you know that the checkboxes are all on a form:

```
var list = new List<CheckBox>();
foreach(var control in this.Controls)
{
    var checkBox = control as CheckBox;
    if(checkBox != null)
    {
        list.Add(checkBox);
    }
}

var checkBoxArray = list.ToArray();
```

If you don't know where the controls are then you will have to search for them.

BTW: The code above uses WinForms. If you are using WPF, Silverlight, Metro,... the container will be named differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do new and then

```
checkboxarray = new CheckBox[] { txtChckBx0, ....}
```

it's two different ways to define an array.
you need to do:

```
CheckBox[] checkboxarray = { txtChckBx0, ....};
```

If you want it to work.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In WinForm

```
List<CheckBox> checkBox = new List<CheckBox>();
// Adding checkboxes for testing...
for (int i = 0; i <= 80; i++)
{
    var cbox = new CheckBox();
    cbox.Name = "txtChckBx"+ i.ToString();
    checkBox.Add(cbox);
    Controls.Add(cbox);

}

List<CheckBox> checkBoxfound = new List<CheckBox>();
// loop though all the controls 
foreach (var item in Controls)
{
    // filter for checkboxes and name should start with "txtChckBx"
    if (item is CheckBox && ((CheckBox)item).Name.StartsWith("txtChckBx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        checkBoxfound.Add((CheckBox)item);
    }
}
```